Maximum switch using RSTP or MSTP
Great to find you mates here.
I am new to Spanning Tree.
According to https://www.etherwan.com/sites/default/files/setting_up_stp-rstp-mstp_and_alpha_ring.pdf
STP can support up to 14 switches
RSTP and MSTP can support up to 40 switches
Why my switches don't support/allow to use priority values more than 61440. 61440 means 15 switches (including root switch). I am using RSTP and should allow priority values up to 163840, if I am not mistaken.
For your information we are using 38 switches connected to each other as a ring topology.
I added the design topology.
[]The design done by a company. My duty is to impement it1

"we are using 38 switches connected to each other as a ring topology." That is almost insane. You should use trees, not strings or loops. Any STP diameter more than seven is asking for trouble. The timing of STP is way off with 38 switches.

I am just implementing the design.
I can[t change the design.
The switches are used along the fence of company for perimeter protection - CCTV.

STP will not work with that design.

I am just implementing the design - I'd recommend raising your concerned voice. I'd outright refuse to implement something like that. It most likely won't be stable.

I don't know who wrote that, or for what hardware, but they're wrong on every point. The default max diameter of STP is 7, messing with timers can double that, but you're asking for trouble. RSTP doesn't really change that. MST has an 8bit hop count / TTL, so in theory can support 256, but very few implementations will allow that, and it tends to fall apart well before then. All STP's are backwards compat just adding extensions, so the only safe bet is "7". Beyond that don't create loops! (many industrial settings chain dozens of devices)

Perimeter CCTV (more likely IP camera in this case) protection does not require a ring design. It requires direct connectivity from each camera back to a central recording server. It sounds like you are trying to use a ring of small switches to extend cabling to reach along a fence or border. That is not how this is done. You should simply use fiber optic for very long runs (power is a separate issue) or make direct cable paths to a central switch in the middle of the perimeter to stay within 100 meters cable length.

To answer your first question:

Why my switches don't support/allow to use priority values more than
61440. 61440 means 15 switches (including root switch). I am using RSTP and should allow priority values up to 163840, if I am not
mistaken.

When configuring Spanning-Tree in a normal "tree" topology, you really only need to configure the Bridge Priority of your two most core/central switches - one as root, (Bridge Priority 0 or 4096) and one to back it up in case of failure (Bridge Priority 4096 or 8192).  The rest of the switches can be left at their default priority (usually 32768) and the network will converge just fine, and fail-over correctly on loss of the root bridge.
Now on to the second part:

For your information we are using 38 switches connected to each other
as a ring topology.

For this topology, as others have mentioned, Spanning-Tree is not appropriate.  If you are using EtherWAN switches as the link above indicates, I would instead look at using their AlphaRing protocol (https://www.etherwan.com/sites/default/files/2023-07/manual_v4.02.4.3.pdf - Page 162) - this will not only allow 38 switches in a Ring, but will converge MUCH faster than Spanning-Tree - in the order of 15-50ms.  You just need to enable it on the two ports on each switch that join to the next nodes in the ring, and it will automatically block one port to break the ring.
Good Luck!

The maximum network diameter for RSTP/MSTP is seven with default parameters.
Any size beyond that requires careful tweaking of the parameters, with the general caveat that you trade larger diameter for slower convergence. 17 switches are certainly possible but I seriously doubt 40.

RSTP and MSTP can support up to 40 switches

It's not about the number of switches but about the diameter, the maximum number of hops between any two nodes. You can easily run a network of hundreds or even thousands of switches with a network diameter of five (at least in theory, that size would create other problems), e.g.

https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2202410&seqNum=4
Any STP variant creates one or more spanning trees on top of your physical network - that's the most 'natural' topology for Ethernet (and most other L2 networks). Accordingly, your physical network should also form a tree. Do not design long chains or rings, they perform worse than a tree.

Why my switches don't support/allow to use priority values more than 61440.

You don't number your switches by priority. Instead, you configure your root bridge with priority 0, the backup root with 1, and leave the rest of the switches at default. Priority values are usually configured as multiples of 4096.

Thanks!
This is the design done by a company. The switches will be around the fence - perimeter protection. On each switch 1-4 IP cameras will be connected to each switch.
